# Split string using loop to specific length sub-units

Tags: c++, loops, substr

I need to split a string into specific lengths, e.g. if user specifies it to units of max length 4, then the loop should run on the original input `"0123456789asdf"` to get `"0123"`, `"4567"`, `"89as"`, `"df"`.

I can't really figure out the best way to do this - and I need it to be in a loop as further processing needs to be done on each subunit of the strong. TIA.

edit: I do not know how long the original string is, and I only know the size of the chunk it needs to become. Also, I need chunks of the string of the specified length, and the last chunk containing the *remainder* of the string (if it is less than the specified length).

Comment: a similar question that probably could help you: [C++: How do I split a string into evenly-sized smaller strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207730/c-how-do-i-split-a-string-into-evenly-sized-smaller-strings)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
string str("0123456789asdf");

for (unsigned i = 0; i < str.length(); i += 4) {
    cout << str.substr(i, 4) << endl;
}
```

Comment: This does not work if the string is not a multiple of 4

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` can take a range as its constructor argument ([constructor 6](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)). Use it:

```
char const str[] = "0123456789asdf";
std::string x(str, str + 4); // "0123"
```

Here, `str` and `str + 4` are pointers to characters into the char array, which are compatible with the `ForwardIterator` concept. (Pointers are iterators)