# Shifting char array right after "inserting" to a given position?

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I've received a task, where I have to change every 5th character of a character array to `=` character and then shift the other elements of the array right, like this: `I like fruit` --> `I lik=e fru=it`.

I have trouble with how to shift the elements after the `=` characters. I was considering something similar to simple sorting, but I just can't imagine how to switch and which elements. Could you help me out, please? Thanks in advance!

I could complete the code this far:

```
#include<cstring>
#include<fstream>

int main(){
    
    char sentence[] = "I like fruit";
    int length = strlen(sentence);
    
    for(int i = 1; i < length; i++){
        if(i % 5 == 0){
            sentence[i] = '=';
        }
    }
    
    std::cout << sentence << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sentence` is of fixed size, you cannot add more characters to it. Is there a reason you are not using `std::string` ?

Comment: Do you have to do it in-place?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number it has to be a char array, sadly I can't use string :( I just left it there by accident, at first I wanted to do with that but then saw the point in my task. Let me correct it. Also, I was thinking about a dynamic char array, would it be possible to do the shift using that?

Comment: Considering `e frui` is 6 characters, shouldn't the output be something like `I lik=e fru=it`?

Comment: @MarkSouls what do you mean by in-place? ^^' if you mean I can use a function to make the shift, I can

Comment: @silverfox ohh yes, that's the correct one, sorry ^^' corrected it

Comment: In place means to operate within original memory, just modifying ```sentence``` in this case. If it doesn't have to be in place, you can make another ```char[]``` and use it as result array.

Comment: `std::string` is a dynamic char array (with some bells and whistles added)

Comment: @MarkSouls it is not possible to add characters to the string "in-place", there is not enough place for them

Comment: Please include the full and complete assignment or exercise text, so we can know all possible requirements and limitations.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Well, we don't really know if the OP is allowed to start with a big enough array or, worse, use `malloc/realloc`.

Comment: @Bob__ if we take only what is written in the question then the array is not big enough. The task is "I have to change every 5th character of a character array". Nevermind, the question maybe needs a little clarification. If they cannot use `std::string`, what can they use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From running your code, it can be seen that the characters would be **replaced**, not **inserted**.

Your code result:

Input : `I like fruit`

Output : `I lik= fru=t`

A viable way is to input a [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), use [`substr()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) to [split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709314/split-string-using-loop-to-specific-length-sub-units) the input into segments of 5, then adding a `=` afterward.

The problem with using `char[]` is that it's of **fixed** size, meaning nothing can be added/removed from it (although you can still modified it normally). `std::string` is dynamic (in general it **is** a dynamic char array with a few differences), so it could change its size.

```
#include<string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string inp; cout << "Input : "; getline(cin, inp);
    int len = inp.length(); string res = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i+=5)
    {
        string tmp = inp.substr(i, 5); //splitting the string
        if (tmp.size() == 5) {tmp += '=';} //adding '='
        res += tmp;
    }
    cout << res;
}
```

Output:

```
Input : I like fruit
I lik=e fru=it
```

More info : [Difference between `std::string` and `char[]` in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287306/difference-between-string-and-char-types-in-c#:%7E:text=A%20string%20is%20a%20class,automatically%20manages%20it%20for%20you.&text=C%2B%2B%20strings%20can%20contain%20embedded,readable%20and%20easier%20to%20use.).