# Number distribution

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Problem: We have x checkboxes and we want to check y of them evenly.

Example 1: select 50 checkboxes of 100 total.

```
[-]
[x]
[-]
[x]
...
```

Example 2: select 33 checkboxes of 100 total.

```
[-]
[-]
[x]
[-]
[-]
[x]
...
```

Example 3: select 66 checkboxes of 100 total:

```
[-]
[x]
[x]
[-]
[x]
[x]
...
```

But we're having trouble to come up with a formula to check them in code, especially once you go 11/111 or something similar. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: What language/environment is this? browser? javascript? Windows application? Gnome? KDE?

Comment: C# but I didn't think it matters that much, pseudocode is fine.

Comment: The question is hill-posed: "evenly" is not well defined. When selecting 5 over 10 evenly may be .x ..xx ...xxx ....xxxx .....xxxxx or even ......xxxxxx.

Comment: That's why I added 3 examples :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a straightforward solution using integer arithmetic:

```
void check(char boxes[], int total_count, int check_count)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < total_count; i++)
        boxes[i] = '-';

    for (i = 0; i < check_count; i++)
        boxes[i * total_count / check_count] = 'x';
}
```

`total_count` is the total number of boxes, and `check_count` is the number of boxes to check.

First, it sets every box to unchecked.  Then, it checks `check_count` boxes, scaling the counter to the number of boxes.

Caveat: this is left-biased rather than right-biased like in your examples.  That is, it prints `x--x--` rather than `--x--x`.  You can turn it around by replacing

```
        boxes[i * total_count / check_count] = 'x';
```

with:

```
        boxes[total_count - (i * total_count / check_count) - 1] = 'x';
```

### Correctness

Assuming `0 <= check_count <= total_count`, and that `boxes` has space for at least `total_count` items, we can prove that:

- No check marks will overlap.  `i * total_count / check_count` increments by at least one on every iteration, because `total_count >= check_count`.
- This will not overflow the buffer.  The subscript `i * total_count / check_count`

  - Will be `>= 0`.  `i`, `total_count`, and `check_count` will all be `>= 0`.
  - Will be `< total_count`.  When `n > 0` and `d > 0`:

    ```
    (n * d - 1) / d < n
    ```

    In other words, if we take `n * d / d`, and nudge the numerator down, the quotient will go down, too.

    Therefore, `(check_count - 1) * total_count / check_count` will be less than `total_count`, with the assumptions made above.  A division by zero won't happen because if `check_count` is 0, the loop in question will have zero iterations.

Answer (score 4):

Let's first assume `y` is divisible by `x`. Then we denote `p = y/x` and the solution is simple. Go through the list, every `p` elements, mark 1 of them.

<del>Now, let's say `r = y%x` is non zero. Still `p = y/x` where `/` is integer devision. So, you need to:</del>

- <del>In the first `p-r` elements, mark 1 elements</del>
- <del>In the last `r` elements, mark 2 elements</del>

<del>**Note:** This depends on how you define *evenly distributed*. You might want to spread the `r` sections with`x+1` elements in between `p-r` sections with `x` elements, which indeed is again the same problem and could be solved recursively.</del>

Alright so it wasn't actually correct. I think this would do though:

Regardless of divisibility:

- if `y > 2*x`, then mark 1 element every `p = y/x` elements, `x` times.
- if `y < 2*x`, then mark all, and do the previous step unmarking `y-x` out of `y` checkboxes (so like in the previous case, but `x` is replaced by `y-x`)

**Note:** This depends on how you define *evenly distributed*. You might want to change between `p` and `p+1` elements for example to distribute them better.

Comment: If y = 100, x = 66, then: r = 100%66 = 34, and p = 100/66 = 1. This makes p-r negative.

Comment: @submachine, yeah, wait, it's something like this, but I'd have to think this better through

Comment: The thing is, we mentally 'rounded' things off when we saw the 100/66 and made it 3/2. This is an arbitrary decision because we see it's close enough. I don't think this can be approximated on a computer with only integer math. Ofcourse, it would be interesting to see how you adjust to it!

Comment: @submachine, see my edit. I wonder though about how to decide when to skin `p-1` and when to skip `p` elements for a better distribution. Somehow I get a feeling this problem is the same as drawing a line in 2D (computer graphics) (You know, Bresenham's algorithm), but the mapping is not so clear in my mind

Comment: It's interesting how the appeal of your answer was good enough for at least 3 people to upvote it, regardless of the correctness. :)

Comment: I was sure I had solved this problem once before but can't seem to find the code :-/

Comment: @DanielMošmondor :)) Yeah I was surprised!!

Answer (score 1):

Say number of checkboxes is C and the number of Xes is N.

You example states that having C=111 and N=11 is your most troublesome case.

Try this: divide C/N.  Call it D.  Have index in the array as double number I.  Have another variable as counter, M.

```
double D = (double)C / (double)N;
double I = 0.0;
int M = N;
while (M > 0) {
    if (checkboxes[Round(I)].Checked) { //  if we selected it, skip to next
        I += 1.0;
        continue;
    }
    checkboxes[Round(I)].Checked = true;
    M --;
    I += D;
    if (Round(I) >= C) { //  wrap around the end
        I -= C;
    }
}
```

Please note that Round(x) should return nearest integer value for x.

This one could work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key is to keep count of how many boxes you expect to have per check.

Say you want 33 checks in 100 boxes. `100 / 33 = 3.030303...`, so you expect to have one check every 3.030303... boxes. That means every 3.030303... boxes, you need to add a check. 66 checks in 100 boxes would mean one check every 1.51515... boxes, 11 checks in 111 boxes would mean one check every 10.090909... boxes, and so on.

```
double count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < boxes; i++) {
    count += 1;
    if (count >= boxes/checks) {
        checkboxes[i] = true;
        count -= count.truncate(); // so 1.6 becomes 0.6 - resetting the count but keeping the decimal part to keep track of "partial boxes" so far
    }
}
```

You might rather use `decimal` as opposed to `double` for `count`, or there's a slight chance the last box will get skipped due to rounding errors.

Answer (score 1):

[Bresenham](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm)-like algorithm is suitable to distribute checkboxes evenly. Output of 'x' corresponds to Y-coordinate change. It is possible to choose initial err as random value in range [0..places) to avoid biasing.

```
def Distribute(places, stars):
    err = places // 2
    res = ''
    for i in range(0, places):
        err = err - stars
        if err < 0 :
            res = res + 'x'
            err = err + places
        else:
            res = res + '-'
    print(res)

Distribute(24,17)
Distribute(24,12)
Distribute(24,5)

output:

x-xxx-xx-xx-xxx-xx-xxx-x

-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x

--x----x----x---x----x--
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick html/javascript solution:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id='container'></div>
<script>
var cbCount = 111;
var cbCheckCount = 11;
var cbRatio = cbCount / cbCheckCount;
var buildCheckCount = 0;

var c = document.getElementById('container');

for (var i=1; i <= cbCount; i++) {
  // make a checkbox
  var cb = document.createElement('input');
  cb.type = 'checkbox';

  test = i / cbRatio - buildCheckCount;
  if (test >= 1) {
    // check the checkbox we just made
    cb.checked = 'checked';
    buildCheckCount++;
  }

  c.appendChild(cb);
  c.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
}
</script>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapt code from [one question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084010/algorithm-for-subdividing-an-array-into-semi-equal-uniform-sub-arrays/8084403#8084403) or [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207730/c-how-do-i-split-a-string-into-evenly-sized-smaller-strings/8208966#8208966) from earlier this month.  Set **`N = x =`** number of checkboxes and **`M = y =`** number to be checked and apply formula `(N*i+N)/M - (N*i)/M` for section sizes.   (Also see Joey Adams' answer.)

In python, the adapted code is:

```
  N=100; M=33; p=0;
  for i in range(M):
     k = (N+N*i)/M
     for j in range(p,k-1): print "-",
     print "x",
     p=k
```

which produces 

`- - x - - x - - x - - x - - [...] x - - x - - - x`
 where [...] represents 25 `--x` repetitions.
With `M=66` the code gives 

`x - x x - x x - x x - x x - [...] x x - x x - x - x`
 where [...] represents mostly `xx-` repetitions, with one `x-` in the middle.

Note, in **C or java**: 
*Substitute* `for (i=0; i<M; ++i)` *in place of* `for i in range(M):`. 
*Substitute* `for (j=p; j<k-1; ++j)` *in place of* `for j in range(p,k-1):`.

**Correctness:**  Note that `M = x` boxes get checked because **`print "x",`** is executed `M` times.

Answer (score 0):

What about using [Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shufflehttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) ?

Make array, shuffle and pick first n elements. You do not need to shuffle all of them, just first n of array. Shuffling can be find in most language libraries.

Comment: I considered using a random algorithm but refrained from using it. It would be weird for a customer to see different checkboxes checked each time he opens the screen, the algorithm would have to give the same result each time.